# holding data in a form in asp.net

Tags: c#

I have a simple inquiry form which includes first name,last name etc....first i inserted the records in it but when i click in the submit button it says you have to log in first to submit the query.so i logged in to the website and i need that data which i inserted first time in the website that is in the inquiry form.....how to keep on holding that data???.....so that i need not write it again.
here is my code below:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["userid"] != null)
            {
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//images//" + str);
                    string path = "~//images//" + str.ToString();
                    con.Open();
                    con.Close();
                    Label1.Text = "File uploaded successfully";
                    main addinfo = new main();
                    string Id = Request.QueryString["id"];
                    string SQL = "insert into mandir(user_id,name,place,description,with_religion_category,with_district,with_religion,photo)values('" + Session["userid"] + "','" + txttemplename.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtaddress.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtdescription.Value + "','" + ddlreligioncategory.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + ddlreligion.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + ddldistrict.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + path + "')";
                    addinfo.saveData(SQL);
                    txttemplename.Text = "";
                    txtaddress.Text = "";
                    txtdescription.Value = "";
                    lblenquirymsg.Text = "Thank you for providing the information";
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "File not uploaded successfully";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                lblinfo.Text = "You Must Login Or Register To give information";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like userid store the entire form fields in a session and retrieve it here

Comment: Can you plz be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use sessions for it. Sessions make use of cookies, which are stored in the client. I've personally used this approach and it works perfectly for my needs :) A sample of this is...

```
Session["whatevername"]=username;
```

And if you want to retrieve data from this value, like if the session ID is still in used, then...

```
if (Session["whatevername"]!=null)
{
  //Whatever you want to do...
}
```

In addition to this... Another way to do this is to save the values as cookies directly... Say you just pressed the login button... Add this code under button click event...

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookieid");
cookie.Values.Add("Username", Username.Text);
cookie.Values.Add("Password", Password.Text);
```

Upon reloading of form... Instead of entering credentials again, you make a code that detects if there are cookies like this...Put this under load event...

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookieid"] != null)
{
    Username.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookieid"]["Username"].ToString();
    Password.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookieid"]["Password"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: yeah i have already done that in my code but i just simply need that inserted values of the form which i did it before logging...how to keep that values so that i need not need to write it again and again????

Answer (score 0):

You need to create session variables when the login is successful. For instance:

```
Session["userid"] = username;
```

Since your code checks for a session with "userid" as the value. username should be the textbox value you inserted.